# I want to print a specific item out of an infinite list

Tags: python, list

I have written a program that does produce a list with infinite items but I struggle printing an individual item from it.

Here's what I have tried:

```
import random


a = 0
users = [a]
if a<210000:
   for x in users:
    users.append(a)
    a = a + 1
    users[a] = random.randrange(0,a)
    #print(x)
else:
  print(users[25])
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Also, your `if` condition will never be met as-is, since it's outside of the for loop that goes on indefinitely. That may be your problem. Move the `if` condition inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Looks like you've nested the `for` loop inside the `if`, whereas the `if` should be nested inside the `for` (at the moment it looks like this will always loop forever)

Comment: Additionally, you are modifying a list while iterating over it. This is ill-advised. Using a `while` loop instead

Comment: You cannot create a list with "infinite items". As @Gershy mentioned your loop condition is infinite. The loop condition says that "I will end when I run out of elements in users". However, you keep adding to users at each iteration.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I had forgotten to alter the position of the if statement, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the if/else statements should go inside the for loop. Otherwise, you only check if a is less than 210000 initially, and then go into the for loop forever. Your code should be:

```
import random

a = 0
users = [a]
for x in users:
  if a<210000:
    users.append(a)
    a = a + 1
    users[a] = random.randrange(0,a)
    #print(a) #uncomment print statement to see 'a' grow
  else:
    print(users[25])
    break
```

This way, we check each time the loop executes whether a is less than 210000. Once a gets large enough, we then print users[25] and break the loop.